# How to expand video cropping frame like native application?

Tags: ios, iphone, video-capture

I have issue with `cropping` video and also need to `expand` video
cropping frame like native application, whenever User tapped on
cropping fame I need to expand video frames(thumbnails) and also want
to crop it, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Need to explanation why down vote?

Comment: Can you explain deeper what you mean when cropping and expanding?

Comment: I have done video cropping for selecting area but In iPhone native application, if there is an large video, then we are press on cropping frame the frame and video thumbnail expand to detail crop, so I need to do this like nave application video cropping functionality, I was already done video cropping but need to crop after expand video frame.

Comment: Some diagrams or drawings could help understanding the question.

Comment: I agree, please explain what better the scenario your working with e.g. what are you trying to make and what are you using for it.

Comment: I was trying to implement video editing with expandable frame, Using long press gesture, whenever user pressed left cropping frame or right cropping frame, frame and thumbnail will be expand and user have able to crop video in detail, but issue is that the detail cropping result is not getting properly, so please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to an open source control that you can use as a foundation.

https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider

This control already generates thumbnails from the source video and draws a linear trim bar with draggable handles that let you set the start/end point of the video. All you'd need to do is add some code to reload the trim bar with detailed images from around the time of the handle that's being dragged at the moment.

This control also comes with a sample app that exports the trimmed video from the selected start and end points.

Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I Have already implementing this things, But now I need to crop video like native application like, if user press and hold on cropping frame, frame and thumbnail will be expand to detail crop, this was an my acctual issue, thanks for your reply